# How do I replace only the paragraphs which are children of a blockquote element?

Tags: php, element, paragraph

Using PHP, how do I replace only the paragraphs which are children of a blockquote element? I need to convert these paragraph elements temporarily while I run some other functions, then change them back to "p" "/p" elements once those functions are finished running. (ie. change "p" "/p" to "ptemp" "/ptemp" or something like that.)

Here's a sample of my code:

```
<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p class="replace-this-element">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>

<p class="do-not-replace-this-element">Some Text</p>

<p class="do-not-replace-this-element">Some Text</p>

<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p class="replace-this-element">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>

<p class="do-not-replace-this-element">Some Text</p>

<p class="do-not-replace-this-element">Some Text</p>

<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p class="replace-this-element">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

Edit: Thanks for your questions, here's some more information. . . I'm altering the rendered markup for the content field of a drupal node using PHP so it's happening server-side. I'm inserting code after the 4th paragraph which needs to be inserted before the DOM is built in the client's browser, so can't use js or jQuery for this. I need to ignore the paragraphs nested in blockquotes so that the code is not embedded within the blockquotes.

My thought was to change the p elements within the blockquotes so that these are ignored when inserting the new code after the 4th paragraph. Then change them back to p elements once the code is inserted. But there certainly may be a better way to ignore the nested p elements.

Following is the code which calls and alters the markup via the drupal template.php file:

```
<?php
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $codeToInsert = '<div>A bunch of stuff to add after the 4th paragraph.</div>';
  $contentToAlter = $variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'];
  $contentToAlter = explode("<p>", $contentToAlter);
  $contentToAlter[3] .= $codeToInsert ;
  $contentToAlter = implode($contentToAlter, "<p>");
  $variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'] = $contentToAlter;
}
```

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly you want php to replace your elements in runtime. PHP is server side, instead I would recommend using JQuery/Javascript

Comment: Do you want to give this HTML code to a PHP code and modify it, or you want to modify it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague so its hard for me to come to a conclusion on what it is you're exactly after but this works.

Using JQuery it changes the `replace-this-element` and converts it to a `h1` (I did this because you specified that you wanted to change these elements to ptemp but ptemp is not an element recognised by html) and then it swaps it back. If you run the snippet you won't be able to see anything happen because the `othermethod()` doesn't have anything inside it.

```js
replace_elements();
other_method();
replace_elements_back();

function replace_elements() {
  $("blockquote div").html('<h1 class="replace-this-element">Some Text </h1>');
}

function other_method() {

}

function replace_elements_back() {
  $("blockquote div").html('<p class="replace-this-element">Some Text </p>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p class="replace-this-element">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>

<p class="do-not-replace-this-element">Some Text</p>

<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p class="replace-this-element">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```